# Oracle APEX | How to Focus Last Added Row In Tabular Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex, tabular-form

I want the below code to add new row to the `Tabular Form` and move focus to the first cell on the (added row)  `for example (#f02_0003)`:

```
    apex.widget.tabular.addRow();
for (i=1;i<100;i=i+1)
// to loop all existing row in order to get the new added row id 
        {
             if( $('#f02_'+('000'+i).slice(-4)).length()>0 )
             // to check whether the row with looped id exists or not
                {
                        continue;
                }
             else 
                {
                        $('#f02_'+('000'+(i-1)).slice(-4)).focus(); 
                        // to focus the expected added row
                        break;
                }
        }
```

It add new row **But** Never focus any cell.

**Help Please!..**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the loop. Then add the following line(assuming that the name of the element under the first column is 'f02'):

```
$("[name='f02']").last().focus();
```